# Change the Range of Gauge Control

Tags: c#, .net, gauge

I'm programming with BeauGauge ActiveX Control([www.beaugauge.com](http://www.beaugauge.com)). I changed the range from 0~100 to 0~42 by calling SetRange, but after I set different range and giving the pointer different value with the function SetValue it's NOT pointing at value I gave him, both pointers (For example I set the value to 37 and it's pointing to 16)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The range setting of the pointer is in ControlLayer2, while settings for text on Gauge is in ControlLayer4.
Maybe you just called SetRange{“ ControlLayer4”…},
You need to call:
SetRange{“ControlLayer2”…}
SetRange{“ControlLayer4”…}